# How to fetch PID of a process using package name in Android Studio without ADB?

Tags: android-studio, memory-management, adb, cpu-usage, pid

I have the package names of all running processes. I want to find CPU and Memory usage of each process using it's PID. I can find PID using ADB commands but I want to fetch the value and display it on phone. ADB gives results in terminal. I tried using Runtime.exec() to run ADB commands through code but it doesn't execute all commands and returns information related to the current application only.

I tried using ActivityManager methods too. It also returned current process info only. Can someone please help me out

Comment: Since about Android 9 (not sure can be 8 or 10) the app sandbox disallows listing other processes. So from within an app you will only see one process: the process of your app itself.

Comment: Can't we run adb command from the app and fetch pid of other processes?

Comment: My Goal is to show live resource usage (CPU, Memory,..) of a particular process. If I can't get PID, is there any other way to fetch this data. So far, I managed to fetch package names of all running processes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.